# Java Given 2 Strings write a method to decide if one is a permutation of the other

Tags: java, permutation

That is a question from Cracking the coding interview.Below is my code:

```
class PalinDrome {

    public static Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String [] args){

        //1st input from user
        System.out.println("Enter 1st string: ");
        String s1= userinput.next().toLowerCase();

        // convert 1st string to char Array

        char [] charS1= s1.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(charS1);

        //2nd input from user
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd string: ");
        String s2= userinput.next().toLowerCase();

        // convert 2nd string to char Array

        char [] charS2= s2.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(charS2);

        if(s1.length()==s2.length() && s1.toCharArray()==s2.toCharArray()){
            System.out.println(" Word 2 is Perm of 1st word");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(" Word 2 is not Perm of 1st word");
        }


    }
}
```

Question: When I use Tom(1st) and 2nd Mot/moT (tried different variations), I always get Not perm of 1st word. There are answers in the book, I want to know whats wrong with this logic. Thank in advance.

Comment: permutation or *palindrome*? They are somewhat different

Comment: Why would you think comparing the strings as character arrays would magically figure out if they contained the same characters regardless of ordering?

Comment: Perm, i did not change the class name,  kept that part from another problem I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment `s1.toCharArray()==s2.toCharArray()` is wrong because you are not really comparing values in the array just the references of those 2 newly created arrays.
You should sort those arrays [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[]))
And then use [`Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(char[],%20char[])) to compare those arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using wether collections nor sorting. ^^

Idea is to mark entries in both Strings/char arrays that are the same character until everything is marked. (after checking the strings for same length)

```
    package PermuteString;

public class Permutation {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "yalla";

    String b = "allay";

    String c = "allas";

    Permutation permutation = new Permutation();

    if (permutation.isPermutationWithoutCollection(a, b))
        System.out.println(a + " is permutation of " + b);

    if (!permutation.isPermutationWithoutCollection(a, c))
        System.out.println(a + " is not a permutation of " + c);

}

public boolean isPermutationWithoutCollection(String string1, String string2) {

    if (string1.length() != string2.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    char[] a = string1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    char[] b = string2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        boolean unChanged = true;

        for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {

            if (a[i] == b[k]) {
                a[i] = 'A';
                b[k] = 'B';
                unChanged = false;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (unChanged) {
            //System.out.println("wawawa");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

Yields:

yalla is permutation of allay

yalla is not a permutation of allas

Really depends on what topic the interview is based (based on using java / based on algorithm).